# NavigationLink on macOS causing source view to appear twice

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

#### Overview:

- On `macOS` when using `NavigationLink`, the source view is appearing twice.
- It only happens on `macOS` (see `print` statements)

#### Questions:

- How to resolve this?
- Is there a workaround?

#### Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let names = ["aaa"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(names, id: \.self) { name in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("dest")) {
                        Text(name)
                            .onAppear {
                                print("\(name) appeared")
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SwiftUI was improved a lot since iOS14 released, but still not unstable with navigation view/navigation link, in my case it's localized navigation bar title. So should wait a bit for next release or file a bug to apple

Comment: Don't rely on number of calls onAppear, it is not (and will not be)  controlled by us. In Apple's vision it means "appear in view hierarchy" but not "on screen", and in view hierarchy it might appear as many times as it is constructed (before become visible on-screen), and this might depend on very many things.

Comment: @Asperi The problem is I have a TextField in the list, so that gets re-created twice resulting in some warning thrown that Binding is changed multiple times

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, simply "attach" the `.onAppear` to your `NavigationLink` not the `Text`.

EDIT-1:

This is the test code I'm using to show that moving the `.onAppear` to the
`NavigationLink` as shown, prints only one on appear.

I'm using macos 12, Xcode 13.2, tested on iMac with macos 12.2.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MacOnlyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    let names = ["aaa"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(names, id: \.self) { name in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("dest")) {
                        Text(name)
                    }
                    .onAppear {
                        print("----> \(name) appeared \n")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @dudette, but the real underlying issue is that I have a TextField in the list, so that gets created twice, so when user types text, there is a warning thrown that the Binding is changed multiple times

Comment: I do not see a `TextField` in your code. Show us what you really have, so we can help you. Does my answer work for you with the code you are showing us?

Comment: This is a simplified example, that doesn't show TextField. If I stop the view appearing twice then it would solve my TextField issue. Code is too big to post, hence the simplified example

Comment: So, does my answer stop the double `onAppear` for you? Works well for me.

Comment: Sorry your answer doesn't resolve my issue

Comment: I've updated my answer with the code I'm using, following your example, to show that ".onAppear" only prints once, as per your question. Does this example code, makes ".onAppear" prints more than once for you?